# Using || after awk ENVIRON replacement

Tags: bash, awk

I'm using awk with a variable to cut log files based on a timestamp:

```
LAST_LOG=$last_log awk 'index($0, ENVIRON["LAST_LOG"]) {y=1;next};y' $log_file ;
```

If the date still exists in the log file it works, but if the log file was archived and replaced with a fresh file `awk` will fail.

I want to fall back to `cat $log_file` if `awk` fails:

```
LAST_LOG=$last_log awk 'index($0, ENVIRON["LAST_LOG"]) {y=1;next};y' $log_file ; \
  || cat $log_file
```

But this syntax returns `syntax error near unexpected token ||`.

Is the line above not a normal function that I can use `&&` or `||` after?

Comment: There are two issues that I see: (1) you are not setting a distinct exit status from your `awk` expression and (2) the misplaced `;`  - compare `false || cat somefile` and `false ; || cat somefile` (it is the latter that's causing the syntax error).

Comment: @steeldriver I don't know what I was thinking when I put that `;` there.

Comment: @steeldriver do you know how I can return `exit 1` if `awk` doesn't match?

Comment: Maybe all it needs is something like `END{exit y==1? 0 : 1` or possibly `END{exit !y}` ?

Comment: thanks, would the format be `;` after my last statement then the `END` like this? `... {y=1;next};y; END{exit y==1? 0 : 1}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is `; ||` in

```
LAST_LOG=$last_log awk 'index($0, ENVIRON["LAST_LOG"]) {y=1;next};y' $log_file ; || cat $log_file
```

The `;` ends the `awk` invocation and the next command starts with `||`, which is a syntax error.

What you want to do is to check whether `y` is not 1 at the end of parsing the log file, and in that case make `awk` return a non-zero exit status:

```
LAST_LOG="$last_log" awk '
  index($0, ENVIRON["LAST_LOG"]) { y = 1; next }
  y                              { print }
  END                            { exit !y }' <"$log_file" || cat <"$log_file"
```

Without the explicit `exit` you will only get a non-zero exit status out of `awk` if some sort of error occurred.

Comment: Note that using redirection avoids problems with files named like `foo=bar.log`,  `-foo-.log` or `-` (and avoids running the commands when the file can't be opened and make for more consistent and often more useful error messages with shells that include the script line number for instance).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Ah, right you are. I'm putting them back.

Answer (score 2):

From the comments, we clearly see the way to fix/tune the PO command.
Following a slightly different gnu-Awk approach:

```
awk -v L=$last '$0 ~ L {y=1;next};y; END{if(!y) system("cat " FILENAME)}' $log
```

- probably the condition `$0 ~ L` can be more specific (ex `$1 <= L` or `$1 == L`)

Comment: What's GNU Awk specific here?  `system()` is POSIX.

Comment: That assumes the name of the file doesn't contain special shell characters (is a command injection vulnerability if the name of the file is not tightly controlled). There are some missing quotes. Note that `-v L=...` expands `\...` sequences, it's better to use ENVIRON.

Comment: @Kusalananda, thank you. I thought system was just gnu. I will remove gnu  .

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas,Thank you for pointing this up. You are right. It is not very rational from me but I hate `ENVIRON` except for exported shell variables.